# How to find out data from more than one tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a mysql based project. I need to find out data from more than one table.
I have searched and found a solution like

```
SELECT * from table_1, table_2 where (condition)
```

But such a solution is fine for few tables,and I have about 57 tables in my database.
Please let me know solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to get data from ALL 57 tables to find the data you're looking for?  What type of data do you have in your tables, and what are you looking to do, exactly?  An example of the tables and the data would be great.

Comment: Maybe you should split the fetch of data into more logical blocks and or look at your DB design. I cannot imagine a scenario where you need to write a join from 57 tables at one go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) your tables. e.g.:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
        INNER JOIN Table2
            ON Table1.table1ID = table2.table1ID
        LEFT JOIN Table3
            ON Table2.Table2ID = table3.table2ID;
```

Unfortunately if you want data from all 57 tables, you will need to JOIN all 57 of them.

The syntax you have used (ANSI 89), while it will work is generally best avoided (I believe there are times when Oracle will optimise these better), ANSI 92 joins are less prone to user error, and (to most people) more legible because the JOIN condition comes immediately after the table. Aaron Bertrand has written a [good article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) on reasons to use ANSI 92 syntax over ANSI 89.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN clause.

```
SELECT table_1.name, table_2.salary, table_3.bonus
FROM employee AS table_1 
INNER JOIN info AS table_2 ON table_1.name = table_3.name;
INNER JOIN account as table_2 On table_2.salary = table_3.salary
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If every table has the same number of columns, you could use a UNION query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (condition)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE (condition)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE (condition)
UNION ALL
...
```